# Apex class test for the trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a question met in the preperation of my apex class test for one trigger.

In the trigger, I have the condition "if (!trigger.isExecuting)" so when I create the apex class test, it doesn't pass after the code in the boucle.

Could you have any ideas how I can jump to the code follows?

Code trigger:
[image]

Code apex class test:
[image]

Thanks a lot in your response.

Best,
Jiahuan

Comment: I don't see why you would ever want to include code in a trigger that's not executed when running the trigger...

Comment: In fact, I have another trigger in another object. When I deploy the trigger in production, it displays the error message "Limit the SQL requete 101". So I just want to add a condition to say that if there is already a trigger executed, we don't launch this trigger. It seems IsExcuting is not a good choice. Do you know how to realise that?

Answer (score 0):

`isExecuting` indicates that the context is a trigger. If you use `if(!Trigger.isExecuting)` in a trigger. It'll never be called. See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Fernando, your response is useful. In fact, I have another trigger in another object. When I deploy the trigger in production, it displays the error message "Limit the SQL requete 101". So I just want to add a condition to say that if there is already a trigger executed, we don't launch this trigger. It seems IsExcuting is not a good choice. Do you know how to realise that?

Comment: Take a look here: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000133752